# "Animating" a MapPolyLine in Silverlight

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, bing-maps

I need to animate a MapPolyLine such that on a given event, the start pin zips up to the end pin. The approach I am considerg is to animate frames such that I divide the MapPolyLine into n number of segments and decrease the TimeSpan ts between each frame along the logic of my chosing (to keep things simple, let's just say ts = ts / 2 after each cycle).

I know that one cannot animate the MapPolyLine, but one can change the appearance of the line by updating the latitude and longitude of the end position. My question concerns timing. My experience with multithreading is minimal, so I did not want to take the risk of a user running into a threading based error that may be difficult to diagnose. Should I:

- use a simple DispatcherTimer and tick method
- use a BackgroundWorker that reports progress every-time the TimeSpan has elapsed
- use a dummy animation and attach an event handler to the rendering event
- solution other than the above mentioned options?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I should add that, at the moment, I'm inclined to using the dummy animation per this post by Mike Snow: http://bit.ly/fFQGxW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use the DispatcherTimer considering the amount of time the animation is going to take - by creating a separate animation object that holds state and its own dispatch timer, it ended up being more efficient than using separate threads because the callback would mean interrupting the main UI thread and based on the requirements it was highly unlikely that there will be more than 2-3 of these animations occuring simultaneously with 95% or greater being only 1 animation at a time.